How can I get all of my Cards to be centered?
Screen Capture of the issue in question
I am working on my first Project, it is a Book-list library.
I can't seem to get the Card components to be centered on the site. It is shifted to the left.
I have all of my Card information in the App.js file, Card.js, and Card.css
I have tried multiple methods, videos, and even tried to see if ChatGPT could give some insight but nothing seems to get them centered.
(I have added a screen capture of the issue above)
Thank you very much
**App.js code below:**

    function App() {

  return (

    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>

        <Navbar />
        <div style={{ marginLeft: '200px', padding: '20px' }}>

          <Routes>
            <Route path="/catalog" element={<Catalog />} />
            <Route path="/favorite" element={<Favorites />} />
            <Route path="/" element={

              <div className="App">

                {/* First Row: */}

                <div className="col">

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img12}
                    imgAlt="Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban"
                    title="Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban"
                    description="Author: J.K. Rowling; Cover design by Olly Moss, 2017"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/import-9781338815283/19690866?ean=9781338815283"
                  />
                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img6}
                    imgAlt="Jaws"
                    title="Jaws"
                    description="Author: Peter Benchley; Cover design by Paul Bacon, 1974"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/jaws-peter-benchley/15279162?ean=9780345544148"
                  />
                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img5}
                    imgAlt="The Great Gatsby"
                    title="The Great Gatsby"
                    description="Author: F. Scott Fitzgerald; Cover art by Francis Cugat, 1925"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/the-great-gatsby-f-scott-fitzgerald/18533627?ean=9780743273565"
                  />

                </div>

                {/* Second Row: */}

                <div className="col">

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img7}
                    imgAlt="Pride and Prejudice"
                    title="Pride and Prejudice"
                    description="Author: Jane Austen; Cover design by Hugh Thomson, 1894"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/pride-and-prejudice-jane-austen/15657135?ean=9780141439518"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img3}
                    imgAlt="I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings"
                    title="I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings"
                    description="Author: Maya Angelou, Cover design by Janet Halverson, 1969"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/i-know-why-the-caged-bird-sings-maya-angelou/8496752?ean=9780375507892"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img11}
                    imgAlt="The Handmaids Tale"
                    title="The Handmaids Tale"
                    description="Author: Margaret Atwood, Cover design by Fred Marcellino, 1986"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/brave-new-world-aldous-huxley/18711990?ean=9780060850524"
                  />


                </div>

                {/* Third Row: */}

                <div className="col">

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img1}
                    imgAlt="Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"
                    title="Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"
                    description="Author: J.K. Rowling; Cover design by Olly Moss, 2016"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/harry-potter-and-the-chamber-of-secrets-minalima-edition-illustrated-edition-volume-2-j-k-rowling/15063913?ean=9780439064866"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img4}
                    imgAlt="The Catcher in the Rye"
                    title="The Catcher in the Rye"
                    description="Author: J.D. Salinge; Cover design by E. Michael Mitchell, 1951"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/the-catcher-in-the-rye-j-d-salinger/114571?ean=9780316769488"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img2}
                    imgAlt="Brave New World"
                    title="Brave New World"
                    description="Author: Aldous Huxley, Cover design by Leslie Holland, 1932"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/brave-new-world-aldous-huxley/18711990?ean=9780060850524"
                  />

                </div>

                {/* Fourth Row: */}

                <div className="col">
                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img8}
                    imgAlt="Slaughterhouse-Five"
                    title="Slaughterhouse-Five"
                    description="Author: Kurt Vonnegut, Cover design by Paul Bacon, 1969"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/slaughterhouse-five-or-the-children-s-crusade-a-duty-dance-with-death-kurt-vonnegut/15551258?ean=9780440180296"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img18}
                    imgAlt="Lord of the Rings"
                    title="Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King"
                    description="Author: J. R. R. Tolkien; Cover design by Johan Egerkrans, 2020"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/song-of-solomon-toni-morrison/285447?ean=9781400033423"
                  />


                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img17}
                    imgAlt="The Color Purple"
                    title="The Color Purple"
                    description="Author: Alice Walker; Cover design by Judith Kazdym Leeds, 1982"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/the-color-purple-alice-walker/285324?ean=9780143135692"
                  />

                </div>


                {/* Fifth Row: */}

                <div className="col">

                  <Card
                    imgAlt="Favorites List"
                    title="Favorites List:"
                    buttonText="View Favorites"
                    link="http://localhost:3000/components/Favorites"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgAlt="Book Catalogs"
                    title="Book Catalogs:"
                    buttonText="View Catalogs"
                    link="http://localhost:3000/components/Catalog"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img14}
                    title="Audible.com"
                    imgAlt="Audible.com"
                    description="Online audiobook and podcast service"
                    buttonText="View Here"
                    link="https://www.audible.com/"
                  />

                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img13}
                    title="NY Times Best Sellers List"
                    imgAlt="NY Times Best Sellers List"
                    description="Authoritatively ranked lists of Best Seller books, from 'The New York Times'"
                    buttonText="View Here"
                    link="https://www.nytimes.com/books/best-sellers/"
                  />


                  <Card
                    imgSrc={img10}
                    imgAlt="Jurassic Park"
                    title="Jurassic Park"
                    description="Author: Michael Crichton; Cover design by Chip Kidd, 1990"
                    buttonText="Learn More"
                    link="https://bookshop.org/p/books/jurassic-park-michael-crichton/14708249?ean=9780345538987"
                  />

                </div>

              </div>
            }
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

Card.js code below:
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./Card.css";

export const Card = ({
    imgSrc,
    imgAlt,
    title,
    description,
    buttonText,
    link,
}) => {

    return (
        <div className="card-container">
            {imgSrc && imgAlt && (
                <img src={imgSrc} alt={imgAlt} className="card-img" />
            )}
            {title && <h1 className="card-title">{title}</h1>}
            {description && <p className="card-description">{description}</p>}
            {buttonText && link && (
                <a href={link} className="card-button-link">
                    <button className="card-button">{buttonText}</button>
                    <Link to={link} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}></Link>
                </a>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;


Welcome to SO. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool [<>] in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet.
